# Equivalente ao setOnItemLongClickListener no Ionic 2

Tags: android, angular, ionic2

Criei uma função no qual quando o usuário der um *click* simples no item, mostra um `Toast`, uma alerta, na tela com o nome deste item:

Função no meu arquivo `.ts`:

```
itemSelected(item: string) {
    this.toastCtrl.showToast("Selected Item: " + item, 'bottom');
}
```

Já o botão está definido desta forma:

```
<button ion-item *ngFor="let item of people" (click)="itemSelected(item)">
  {{ item.firstname }}
</button>
```

Isso funciona normalmente, no entanto agora gostaria de criar uma lista de opções quando o usuário fizer um *click* longo no item. No Android nativo é possível fazer isso usando o método `setOnItemLongClickListener`, porém não sei qual seria o equivalente no Ionic. Qual método equivalente ao `setOnItemLongClickListener` no Ionic 2?

Comment: sao seria o `on-hold` ?

Comment: @NeuberOliveira não sei. É?!

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/onHold/

Comment: Pelo menos no ionic 1 é, é so testar.

Comment: Testado: não funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Em ionic 2, você pode fazer isso com o **ionic-long-press**.

É preciso rodar o comando:

```
npm install --save ionic-long-press
```

No app.module.ts:

```
import { LongPressModule } from 'ionic-long-press';

imports: [
  LongPressModule,
  IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
],
```

No seu html:

```
<button ion-button (click)="init()" ion-long-press 
     [interval]="4000" (onPressStart)="pressed()" 
     (onPressing)="mantendoPessionado()"
     (onPressEnd)="released()" color="danger">
</button>
```